# how to parse two times with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file like this (sep = ;) :

```
kit;;;;;;;
Software Version = cti;;;;;;;
Date And Time of Export = 06/02/20  14:14:11;;;;;;;
Experiment Name = taqpath-AB17500-platename;;;;;;;
Instrument Software Version = ;;;;;;;
Instrument Type = sds7500fast;;;;;;;
Instrument Serial Number = ;;;;;;;
Run Start Date = Tue Jun 02 12:00:40 CEST 2020;;;;;;;
Run End Date = Tue Jun 02 13:14:42 CEST 2020;;;;;;;
Run Operator = FE;;;;;;;
Batch Status = VALID;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
```

And I want to parse the 4th line and past some infos in line 7 and 12 to have the following output:

```
kit;;;;;;;
Software Version = cti;;;;;;;
Date And Time of Export = 06/02/20  14:14:11;;;;;;;
Experiment Name = taqpath-AB17500-platename;;;;;;;
Instrument Software Version = ;;;;;;;
Instrument Type = sds7500fast;;;;;;;
Instrument Serial Number = AB17500;;;;;;;
Run Start Date = Tue Jun 02 12:00:40 CEST 2020;;;;;;;
Run End Date = Tue Jun 02 13:14:42 CEST 2020;;;;;;;
Run Operator = FE;;;;;;;
Batch Status = VALID;;;;;;;
Method = taqpath;;;;;;;
```

I try to -F "=" the line 4 in order to have the correct infos in $2 but after I don't know how to re-parse a second time with -F "-".

Do you have idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to use `split()` in `awk`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `split`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS=" = "}
    NR==4{split($2,a,"-")}
    NR==7{$2=a[2]}
    NR==12{$2=a[1]$0; $1="Method"}
1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , it works very well . Now I'm familiar with split in awk

Comment: `$2=a[1]$0; $1="Method"` is IMHO less clear than `{$0="Method = " a[1] $0}` or, if you prefer, `{$0="Method" OFS a[1] $0}`. It's also less efficient since assigning to 2 fields will cause awk to recompile $0 twice.